# Select a record that has a relationship with a number of other IDs in a junction table

Tags: sql, sqlite

- I am using an SQLite 3 database.
- I have 2 tables with a many-to-many relationship. As a result, I also have a junction table to persist this relationship. Below is a representation of something similar to what I have, with made up data etc.

Teacher Table:

```
+----+------------+
| ID |    Name    |
+----+------------+
| 1  | TeacherOne |
| 2  | TeacherTwo |
+----+------------|
```

StudentTable:

```
+----+------------+
| ID |    Name    |
+----+------------+
| 1  | StudentOne |
| 2  | StudentTwo |
+----+------------+
```

Teacher_Student (Junction Table):

```
+-----------+-----------+
| TeacherID | StudentID |
+-----------+-----------+
|         1 |         1 |
|         1 |         2 |
|         2 |         1 |
+-----------+-----------+
```

What I want is to select only the `TeacherID` which has a record linking it with both `StudentID` is 1 and `StudentID` is 2. In this case, that would give me only `TeacherID` is 1.

I have already tried the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT t_s.*
FROM Teacher_Student AS t_s
WHERE StudentID IN (1, 2)
```

And this returns me any records that have a `StudentID` of either 1 or 2. I have searched for an answer but have been unable to find anything which has helped me so far, so asking as a last resort.

Comment: You want to find a teacher that has a record in the Teacher_Student table per each student or just for 2 specific student?

Comment: Just for a specific combination of students, in this case student 1 and student 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select `TeacherID` which has a record in `Teacher_Student` table for each student; you can use this query:

```
SELECT ts.TeacherID
FROM (
  SELECT TeacherID, COUNT(StudentID) AS cnt
  FROM teacher_student
  GROUP BY TeacherID) ts
JOIN (
  SELECT COUNT(*) As sCnt 
  FROM student) s
ON ts.cnt = s.scnt
```

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/4e62db/5)**

---

You can use this query for selecting two specific student:

```
SELECT ts.TeacherID
FROM (
  SELECT TeacherID, COUNT(StudentID) AS cnt
  FROM teacher_student
  WHERE StudentID IN (1,2)
  GROUP BY TeacherID) ts
WHERE cnt = 2
```

That will also remove a teacher that has two connection to a student.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you I have been struggling with this one for a while!